# Information theoretic common sequence agreement (not secret key)

Tags: it.information-theory, coding-theory

Supposing Alice and Bob share $\rho$-correlated sequences in $\{0,1\}^n$, what coding theory based schemes are available for Alice and Bod to extract sequences $A,B\in\{0,1\}^n$ respectively such that $A,B$ agree on $k(n,\rho)$ bits for cases  (I am not worried about secrecy):

$(1)$ Alice and Bob communicate.

$(2)$ Alice and Bob do not communicate.

Assume Alice and Bob exchange $m(n,\rho)$ bits in total to agree on $k(n,\rho)$ bits.

What is the min rate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{m(n,\rho)}{k(n,\rho)}$?

Rather more generally, completely, what is explicit formula for the curve $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(m(n,\rho),k(n,\rho))\subseteq\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Your second question may ask for how much Gacs-korner common information can be extracted in bits?

Comment: Could you explain in more details in answer?

Answer (score 2):

According to G-K common information $K(X;Y) = \mathop {Sup{\rm{ }}H(V)}\limits_{V = f(X) = g(Y)}$ :

Roughly speaking, it measures the amount of common randomness that can be separately extracted from either marginal of the two jointly distributed random variables from the $\rho$-correlated i.i.d. generated sequences $(A^n,B^n)$. You need to reformulate your questions in language of common information. Also, for more details, you may look at the known paper by GK:

P. Gacs and J. Korner, “Common information is far less than mutual information”, Problems of Control and Information Theory, vol. 2, no. 2, pp. 119–162, 1972.